# Need to get correct data from Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I take data from Firestore by user id. I need to display data in a TextFormField and be able to update it immediately on button click. There was a problem, because I'm not building a list, but I need to display data for only one id. How do I correctly access the firestore elements, to the id, I need to get these lines, only this code does not work for me `var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.docs.data()!; String docID = snapshot.data!.docs.id; String title = noteInfo['title'];` You need to refer to elements only **without `[index]`** I will sharpen that I do not have a list. Does anyone know how to contact them correctly? I will be grateful for help

**firestore_repository**

```
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final CollectionReference _mainCollection = _firestore.collection('users');

class Database {
  static String? userUid;

  static Future<void> addItem({
    required String bisName,
    required String bisAddress,
    required String contactName,
    required String contactEmail,
    required String phoneNumber,
    required String progName,
    // required String progYears,
  }) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info').doc();

    Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{
      'bisName': bisName,
      'bisAddress': bisAddress,
      'contactName': contactName,
      'contactEmail': contactEmail,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      'progName': progName,
      // 'progYears': progYears,
    };

    await documentReference
        .set(data)
        .whenComplete(() => print('User info added to the database'))
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
  }

  static Future<void> updateItem({
    required String bisName,
    required String bisAddress,
    required String contactName,
    required String contactEmail,
    required String phoneNumber,
    required String progName,
    required String docId,
  }) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info').doc(docId);

    Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{
      'bisName': bisName,
      'bisAddress': bisAddress,
      'contactName': contactName,
      'contactEmail': contactEmail,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      'progName': progName,
    };

    await documentReference
        .update(data)
        .whenComplete(() => print('User info updated to the database'))
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
  }

  static Stream<QuerySnapshot> readItems() {
    CollectionReference usersInfoCollection =
        _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info');

    return usersInfoCollection.snapshots();
  }

  static Future<void> deleteItem({
    required String docId,
  }) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info').doc(docId);

    await documentReference
        .delete()
        .whenComplete(() => print('User info deleted to the database'))
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
  }
}
```

**profile_screen**

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreen();
}

class _ProfileScreen extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Database.readItems(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data != null) {
                  return _userInfo(snapshot);
                }
              }
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }

  Widget _userInfo(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    var userInfo = snapshot.data!.docs;
    // String docId = snapshot.data.docs;
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Form(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Business Name".toUpperCase(),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: secondaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: primaryColor,
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: do you only need one element form the info collection or all items in the collection? if one then you can add .limit(1) to the query

Comment: var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.docs.data()!;
You need to refer to elements only without [index] I will sharpen that I do not have a list

Comment: then there is a missleading code there, because CollectionReference usersInfoCollection = _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info'); shows you want for a userUid the collection info what a list is. so then my answer is right according to your code, but you code is incorrect to what you want

Comment: Please, could you tell me how to pull data from firestore in my case and show it not in ListView but in TextFormField? Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### according to the comments:

to save properties in the firestore i would do this by adding a document with `documentId` `info` to the user document.

The the query would look like this: `_mainCollection.doc(userUid).doc('info');`

and in the widget:

```
var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.data()!;
String docID = snapshot.data!.id;
String title = noteInfo['title'];
```

#### old answer:

try this:

```
var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!;
String docID = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id; String title = noteInfo['title'];
```

you need the `index` because the docs is of type `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` and with `.data()` you get the Map of the contents.

where the `index` is the zero based index of the element you want to get from the info collection

Comment: And if I don’t have a list, but just the data, I need to show one user at a time in the TextFormField. Well then I can not use [index] produces an error.

Comment: i understand but you get a collection with _mainCollection.doc(userUid).collection('info'); from one user. as i mention in the answer the info collection is of type List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<...>>, for a more correct answer you have to describe the database model a bit

Comment: Please, could you tell me how to pull data from firestore in my case and show it not in ListView but in TextFormField? Can this be done?

Comment: therefore i need additional infos. what is the content of the collection info? or is info only a document in the user document?

Comment: There is currently no data in the Firestore. The data I want to write is in the firestore_repository. I need that when the user registers, he can enter his data in the TextFormField and by clicking on the button this data is written to the Firestore. And so that the user could log in at any moment, his data was displayed in the TextFormField and he could edit / change them and press the button again and the data would be updated.
Here is how the application works

Comment: @MaxZubko is it working now?

Comment: no, it doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @MaxZubko what error are you getting when you use this solution? Can you please share it with us?